# OneToMany returns null after insert

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

there is order entity:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "`order`")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Order extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(name = "customerID")
    @NotNull
    private long customerID;

    @Column(name = "masterID")
    @NotNull
    private long masterID;

    @Column(name = "serviceID")
    @NotNull
    private long serviceID;

    @Column(name = "time")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private Date time;

    @Column(name = "eventID")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String eventID;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerID",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "serviceID",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private Service service;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "masterID",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false)
    private Master master;

    public String getDescription() {
        return String.format("Description: \n" +
                        "   Customer : \n" +
                        "       Name : %s \n" +
                        "       Last name : %s \n" +
                        "       Phone number : %s \n" +
                        "   Master : \n" +
                        "       Name : %s \n" +
                        "       Lat name : %s \n" +
                        "   Service: \n" +
                        "       Name : %s \n" +
                        "       Cost : %s \n",
                customer.getFirstName(),
                customer.getLastName(),
                customer.getPhoneNumber(),
                master.getFirstName(),
                master.getLastName(),
                service.getName(),
                service.getCost());
    }
}
```

Service entity:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "service")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Service extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    @NotNull
    private double cost;

    @Column(name = "execution_time")
    @NotNull
    private long executionTimeMillis;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "service", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Order> order = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "services")
    private List<Master> masters;


}
```

and Order service method:

```
 @Override
    public Order save(Order entity) {
        entity = super.save(entity);
        Event event = new Event();
        EventDateTime startTime = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(new DateTime(entity.getTime()));
        EventDateTime endTime = new EventDateTime()
                .setDateTime(new DateTime(new Date(startTime
                        .getDateTime()
                        .getValue() + entity.getService()
                        .getExecutionTimeMillis())));
        event.setStart(startTime);
        event.setEnd(endTime);
        event.setDescription(entity.getDescription());
        event.setSummary(entity.getService().getName());
        event = googleEventService.createEvent(entity.getMaster().getCalendarID(), event);
        entity.setEventID(event.getId());
        return entity;
    }
```

So, for order endpoint I pass following json :

```
{
    "customerID" : 4,
    "masterID" : 4,
    "serviceID": 5,
    "time": "2023-08-11 15:30:00"
}
```

Customer, Master, Service are present in DB with correspond ID's

and get following error:

```
 Cannot invoke "com.servicebuilder.entities.Service.getExecutionTimeMillis()" because the return value of "com.servicebuilder.entities.Order.getService()" is null
```

During debugging I found that **Service** class is null in **Order** class after save or if I try to do get() for this order by ID (after save using evaluate expression in IDE).

But if I perform getById() for saved order after exception, all nessesary links are present in **Order** class

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved it. just need to add
entityManager.refresh(entity);

from import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;